# Laravel 8 - I have an error in when using method in Model when using paratheses with the method

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have two models [The relation is one-many / Category-Trip]:

Category Model Code:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
            'id',
            'category_name',
            'category_desc',
            'category_img',
        ];


    public function trip() {
        return $this->hasMany(Trip::class);
    }

}
```

Trip Model Code:

```
class Trip extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description',
        'max_visitors',
        'price',
        'date',
        'image',
        'guide_id',
        'category_id',
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

when I use this code, I will get this error:

> TypeError Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent():
> Argument #1 ($content) must be of type ?string,
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo given, called in
> C:\Users\Orange\Desktop\ON
> GITHUB\Tours-Booking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Response.php
> on line 72

```
$trip = Trip::findOrFail(1);
return $trip->category();
```

But when write this without paratheses, i will not get this error, what is the problem?

```
$trip = Trip::findOrFail(1);
return $trip->category;
```

Comment: The method returns a `BelongsTo` relationship object. The property returns the related `Category` object. What is the point of the question? Just don't use the code that causes an error!

Comment: Thank you @miken32

Answer (score 1):

As a user explained (but not fully):

You are returning a relationship in your controller, but that is not valid (based on the error). Because `BelongsTo` cannot be serialized to a `string`, it tries to return the `BelongsTo` object, hence giving you that error (look, it is saying it is wanting `null` or a `string`, but you are returning `BelongsTo`).

When you do `$model->relation` (without `()`), that means it will try to get all the data that satisfies the relation and store it as a `Category` in `$model->relation` (because it is a `BelongsTo`), but when you use `$model->relation()` you creating a `query` so you can query the relation with whatever you want/need, like `$model->relation()->where('status', 'Active')->get()`...

You have 2 solutions: either return `$trip->category` (it is going to be a `Category` object/model) or `$trip->category()->get()` or any query but use `->get()` (will return a `Collection`) or `->first()` (will return a `Category` model) at the end...

Read the documentation again so you understand better now: [Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships) and [First](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) vs [Get](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#building-queries) and [BelongsTo documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-defining-the-inverse-of-the-relationship).

Comment: I knew the difference between them, Thank you so much guys,

Answer (score 0):

When you call the method its instantiating a eloquent instance in which you can extend it to a query which will give you a Category model

example (this might not be the most appropriate example)

```php
$trip = Trip::findOrFail(1);

return $trip->category()->where('category_name', 'something')->first();
```

And the latter returns a collection.

Comment: aha okay thank you

Comment: the latter does not return a Collection it returns a Model instance or `null` ... it is a `BelongsTo`